# The review stars are not getting displayed on my website

Tags: html

This is my code to display review stars on my webpage. But unfortunately I'm not getting the output.

```
<div class="stars">
                            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: *but it is not getting printed* Do you mean it does not appear when trying to **print** the page? Also, your HTML is invalid. It doesn't have a  `DOCTYPE` and the `head` element is never closed.

Comment: You are missing `font-awesome` CDN Link

Comment: Ya. The pic and the name is getting printed perfectly , only the stars are not getting displayed on the page

Comment: @connexo I tried the changes you told me but I'm still not getting the stars on my page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy `font-awesome` CDN link and paste in `head`

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <!-----Stylesheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@1,600&display=swap">
    <!-----Copy this CDN LINK-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  </head>
    <body>
        <div class="testimonials">
            <div class="inner">
                <h1>Testimonials</h1>
                <div class="border"></div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="testimonial">
                            <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="name">Chris Gomes</div>
                            <div class="stars">
                                <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```